# Page containing multiple Gridview RowEditing Event not firing

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

Web page is designed using .Net framework 4.5. Web pages contains 3 Grid views as follows:

[image]

Code for Gridview is as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdADetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="tGrid" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="grdADetails_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="grdADetails_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdADetails_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdADetails_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="grdADetails_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdADetails_RowUpdating">
                    <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mode Of Transport">
                                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpTMode" runat="server" CssClass="trvGridCmbBox" Width="90%">
                                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="tGridTotal" style="Height : 25px;"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="GridEditArea" style="Height : 25px;">
                                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpNTMode" runat="server" CssClass="trvGridCmbBox" Font-Size="8pt" Width="98%">
                                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTMode" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:EResources, lblModeOfT %>" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblESubTypeCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ESubTypeCode") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTMode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TMode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="12%" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                        //For Date part using Ajax Control
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Departure On">
                                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeptOn" runat="server" CssClass="trvGridTextBox" Text='<%# Bind("DeptOn") %>' Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceDeptOn" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDeptOn" Enabled="true" Animated="true" EnabledOnClient="true" EnableViewState="true" FirstDayOfWeek="Default"/>
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="tGridTotal" style="Height : 25px;"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="GridEditArea" style="Height : 25px;">
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDeptOn" runat="server" CssClass="trvGridTextBox" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceNewDeptOn" runat="server" Enabled="true" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtNewDeptOn" Animated="true" EnabledOnClient="true" EnableViewState="true" FirstDayOfWeek="Default"/>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDepartureOn" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:EASEResources, lblDeparOn %>" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDeptOn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeptOn") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                        //Same as above for remaining columns
                        //For Edit button column
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" />
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/remove1.png" />
                                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="tGridTotal" style="height: 25px"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="GridEditArea" aria-orientation="vertical" style="height: 25px">
                                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew" CssClass="trvGridTextBox" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEdit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:EResources, lblEdit %>" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/edit.png" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="4%" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Remaining two grid views are created in the similar format.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdTDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="travelGrid" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdTDetail_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="GrdTDetail_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GrdTDetail_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GrdTDetail_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GrdTDetail_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GrdTDetail_RowUpdating">
               <Columns>
            //Other Column Code
            //Edit Column Code.
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                                 <EditItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" />
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/remove1.png" />
                                                 </EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                                        <table border="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="travelGridTotal" style="Height : 25px;"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="GridEditArea" style="Height : 25px;">
                                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNewACC" CssClass="trvGridTextBox" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEdit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:EResources, lblEdit %>" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/edit.png" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="4%" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="travelGridhead" /
</asp:GridView>
```

//3rd Gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdOtherExp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" CssClass="travelGrid" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="True" Width="100%" OnRowCancelingEdit="GrdOtherExp_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="GrdOtherExp_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GrdOtherExp_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="GrdOtherExp_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GrdOtherExp_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GrdOtherExp_RowUpdating">
                 <Columns>
        //Other Column Code
        //Edit Column Code
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" />
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/close.png" />
                   </EditItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="WIDTH: 100%">
                <tr>
                     <td class="travelGridTotal"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td class="GridEditArea">                                                   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNewOExp" CssClass="trvGridTextBox" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/save.png" Height="16px" Width="16px" />
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEdit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:EResources, lblEdit %>" Width="100%"></asp:Label>
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/edit.png" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="2%" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="travelGridhead" /
</asp:GridView>
```

Each grid view has its own **RowEditing, RowDataBound, RowUpdating, RowCancelEditing** events. Gridview functionality is as follows:

1. User can enter data from footer row and using Save button having
   command name as 'AddNew' saves the entered data to Item template in 
   row format. RowCommand event code is as follows:

   ```
   protected void grdADetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {             
        DataTable dtADetails = (DataTable)ViewState["dtAccDetails"];
        ViewState["dtADetails"] = dtADetails;
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            //function to add data
            //function to check required fields
         }

    }
   ```
2. User can edit and update the row data on RowEding event. Row edit button has command name as 'Edit'.

   ```
    protected void grdADetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
         grdADetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
         DataTable dtADetails = (DataTable)ViewState["dtADetails"];// cache data to session        
          //Code for editing the functionality.
    }
   ```
3. User can save the edited row data or cancel the editing.

After publishing the pages to production server only one grid view events get fired, remaining two grid view events do not gets fired. Each editing button has command name as 'Edit' to fire edit event. Each

Comment: Post the code for the Grids from the Design view

Comment: When do you databind the other non-working grids? You should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)`.